# What to do about Windows activation messages with a legal version?

Tags: windows-7

I recently installed Windows 7 for a fourth time due to virus problems. Windows is now telling me that I need to activate it.

I have a legal retail copy of Windows from a PC store. However I'm afraid that Microsoft will deactivate my copy of Windows if I don't buy another license.

What can I do?

Comment: Journeyman and CarlF are right, MS should be fine.  At worst if you say that the current install is the one that is legit then it will be the other installs that will be marked as bad.  If you still had them around they they would likely die after the next time Windows Update is run, but as you have reinstalled then there should be nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 5):

Call MS if they ask you to ,else activate it online. Nothing will happen - it should work fine.

They arn't trying to force you to buy another copy or anything. People activate windows all the time after all. If you're REALLY annoyed by this, consider making a disk image post install

Edit: In addition - you should probably change your AV and habits if you're continually having virus problems

Comment: +1 MS will assist and making an image is great advice.

Comment: As long as you only have windows installed on a single computer, you can activate it as many times as you need.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you haven't installed it on different PCs simultaneously (defined as having different motherboards) Microsoft will be happy to help you get it activated. You aren't doing anything wrong.

If you've been installing on multiple different computers, then you do in fact need to buy another license.

Comment: >>> If you've been installing _simultaneously_ on multiple different computers, then you do in fact need to buy another license. <<<

Comment: i have installed it to 2 pc's... but i still have my old cade... so in fact i can proof that i did not put it to a friend's pc... or anything like that so...